# Finding secondary Owners of Security groups using ADSI Searcher

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to find all owners and secondary owners of security groups within my environment

Could someone please advise me on how i could amend my option 1 command to include secondary owners?
Or any other command that i can use ADSI searcher for to get this information

Thanks,
Ryan

I have tried tackling this 2 ways:

1. find the specific user I am after and reporting back on any groups this person is an owner of - using the below

## Distinguished Name of the user

```
$DN = "CN=***"
```

## Retrieve the groups managed by this user

```
$groups = ([ADSISearcher]"(&(objectCategory=group)(ManagedBy=$DN))").findall()
foreach ($group in $groups) 
{
$group.properties.samaccountname | out-file C:\users\...
}
```

this works to an extent but does not return any groups that the user is a secondary owner of.

The second way I am doing this is also looking at the specific groups that i know have multiple owners and trying to report back the necessary property for the secondary owner but having no luck

Comment: Active Directory doesn't natively have a concept of "secondary owner". How would you manually gather this information?

Comment: Thank for this we have an internal tool that I have used to manually check some of the groups i have outputted from the above scripts and can see some of these groups have secondary owners.

then when running the ocmmand against a secondary owner it doesnt get listed as an owner of the group suppose becuase i am using manage by field.

Just wasnt sure if there was another property that contained secondary owners

Comment: Can you share the source code for this internal tool? Or perhaps tell us which AD attributes the tool uses to keep track of "secondary owners"?

Comment: you need to tell us what is considered a "secondary owner" as this is not an Active Directory standard attribute as Mathias noted above. We can't help you otherwise. It might be a custom attribute used in your Domain but you need to find this out.

Comment: Ok thank you for the above I will check this and get back to you if possible